# Is there a list of standard keystrokes that includes "Open with External Editor"?

Tags: applications, desktop

Apple has [a list of standard keystrokes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236), but it doesn't include "Open in External Editor", which I'm sure I've seen in various apps (although I might not be remembering the wording exactly).

So I'd be happiest with a more complete list of keystrokes, but if nothing else I'll accept the keystroke conventionally used for that command.

Comment: I'm not sure it's common enough to have a specific key command, but any function with a menu item can be given a key command.

Comment: It's a command I've seen in multiple apps, and I'm fairly sure the keystroke was consistent amongst them.  I just don't remember what they were so I can't check.  And searching hasn't turned up anything.

Comment: As you can't remember which apps, & I have no graphics apps here with an 'Open in External Editor' except 'Photos' [which has Cmd/Return for 'open in last-used external editor' instead] then I guess we're stuck.

Comment: I just looked at Photos, and it has "Edit With..." and then a menu of every app that might be able to handle the selected image(s), so it may be that Apple has moved away from something like "Edit in External Editor"...